# How to animate pseudoelement on after hover?

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm trying to animate a pseudoelement when a user leaves it's `:hover` state. Right now, I just have a div with 3 `li` in it, and I'm animating a pseudoelement on the bottom border:

**CODEPEN:**
https://codepen.io/Sackadelic/pen/eYZJNbZ

I can get the pseudoelement to animate on the hover, but I'm struggling getting a smooth transition back to it's normal state after the cursor leaves the hover area. I tried adding a `transition` property to the parent element, but that doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

**HTML**

```
 <div class="container">
     <nav class="nav">
         <li>HOME</li>
         <li>ABOUT</li>
         <li>CONTACT</li>
     </nav>
 </div>
```

**SCSS**

```
$color: #bada55;

body {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    background-color: #222;
    color: #fff;
}

.container {
    padding: 2rem 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.nav {
    display: flex;


    li {
        list-style: none;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 2rem;
        margin: 20px;
        padding: 10px;
        position: relative;
        transition: 0.2s;

        &:hover {
            color: #bada55;
            transition: 0.2s;


            &:before {
                content: "";
                background-color: #bada55;
                width: 100%;
                height: 3px;
                position: absolute;
                display: block;
                top: 4rem;
                left: 0;
                overflow: hidden;
                animation: slide 0.5s;
                transition: 0.2s;
            }
        }
    }
}

@keyframes slide {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateX(-20px);
        width: 0%;
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateX(1);
        width: 100%
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't really need the `animation` here, but, more importantly the pseudoelement should be on `li` at all times, with the normal (hidden) state as the default, and the hover state with the values that should change on hover:

```
.nav {      
    display: flex;

    li {
        list-style: none;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 2rem;
        margin: 20px;
        padding: 10px;
        position: relative;
        transition: 0.2s;
        // the default state - will animato to it after the pointer is out
        &:before {
                content: "";
                background-color: #bada55;
                width: 100%;
                height: 3px;
                position: absolute;
                display: block;
                top: 4rem;
                left: 0;
                overflow: hidden;
                transition: 0.5s;
                opacity: 0;
                width: 0%;
                transform: translateX(-20px);
            }
        
        &:hover {
            color: #bada55;
            transition: 0.2s;
            // the hover state
            &:before {
                opacity: 1;
                width: 100%;
                transform: translateX(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you forget `display: flex` in `nav` :)

Comment: it's not relevant to the answer :)

Comment: i know it will work without it, but the order of the menu items is simply out of order. You gave a great solution :)

Comment: Good job @sergey kuznetsov